# Where exactly to place codeigniter files

Tags: php, codeigniter, security, subdirectory

I've been using codeigniter for a few months, and for my first couple projects I've just put all the files in the root. It's working okay that way, but a reading of the manual suggests for security reasons the system and application files should be moved--while index.php should be in the root.

I'm starting a new project, going back and reading the directions again, and trying to do exactly what they say to do this time. However, I'm having trouble understanding the following instructions,  given in [this page](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/index.html) of the manual:

1. "Install the CodeIgniter folders and files to your server. Normally the index.php file will be at your root."
2. "For the best security, both the system and any application folders should be placed above web root so that they are not directly accessible via a browser."

So, reading this, I don't really understand exactly where I am supposed to put the files. Currently, as unzipped, it's a folder I've called codeigniter, with the all the ci files: system, application, user guide, index.php etc.

So my new Web site currently has this structure:
--www.mywebsite.com
------Public

Should I make it this?

```
--www.mywebsite.com
-----codeigniter
--------application
--------system
--------assets
--------user manual
-----------Public
______________index.php
```

So basically only index.php would be in my root? (And maybe assets and user manual if I want?)

I did read somewhere that if I move system and application files I need to change their path--that should be easy enough, but I want to make sure I am correctly understanding what the ci manual is suggesting before I invest all the time in making the new setup work properly.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

www.mywebsite.com (folder where its located/root) - (Ex: If AWS - `/opt/webapps/mysite/`)

```
other
    - application
    - system
    - assets
index.php
.htaccess <-- mainly to remove index.php from URL and other stuffs as well
```

then in `index.php` (on root)

```
$system_path = 'other/system'; # Line 100
$application_folder = 'other/application'; # Line 117
```

When calling CSS/JS/Images on `assets` folder

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url()?>other/assets/boostrap.css">
```

**Hence you can revoke permission to System folder with the help of `.htaccess`.** (They(Codeigniter Team) already did that). If you open system folder there is file called `.htaccess`. Open it you can see something like this

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

---

**What I suggest you to do from security**

1. Set `base_url()` correctly
2. Use Codeigniter Input methods. (to prevent injections. [read more on this](http://defencely.com/blog/10-popular-ways-hackers-hack-website/))

---

**Resources of links**

1. [Security - Codeigniter.com](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/security.html)
2. [Some more about Security -  tutorialspoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/codeigniter/codeigniter_security.htm)

Comment: Thank you Abdulla!

Comment: No problem. happy to help :)

Comment: Yes, I will totally--- I took a pic of what I have now. Is this correct? http://i.imgur.com/fLSiJSl.jpg

Comment: @Cyclist that's how CI comes. didn't saw any changes on it

Comment: Hi again... I'm not changing ci at all-just trying to figure out where to put it! I realized the last pic I sent didn't put application and system files above the root. Here's my second attempt. If I understand it correctly, the root in my example is "public," and I moved CI's index.php file to public (from the ci folder)--since the instructions seem to say index.php should be in the root. I put the CI folder with systems/applications above the root. here's my latest....would you be kind enough to tell me if this looks right? http://i.imgur.com/ZWDd8OU.jpg

Comment: I don't think so moving outside will load your app. do as i suggest. Cz no one know your file structure

Comment: Thank you for your help! I think I'm a little bit mentally challenged when it comes to file hierarchies, but if I understand your suggestion correctly everything is just going together in the root?

Comment: The answer was helpful and well-presented, so I upvoted! But I haven't accepted it because my question was on how to follow the codeigniter manual's instruction to put application and system files above the Web root. Abdulla's solution does not appear to do this. Based on a discussion in codeigniter forums I decided to use this structure: https://github.com/jedi-academy/CodeIgniter3.1-starter1. It also doesn't follow the manual, but apparently it is how things will be structured in the upcoming Codeigniter4 version. Very possibly no one follows the manual?